# Postman Webservice PHP Curl Code POST request giving forbidden error when run in local

Tags: php, web-services, curl, postman

In postman code snippet section I can get the working code of my POST request as below. **(Replaced credentials with dummy values)**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://mpop.hepsiburada.com/product/api/products/import',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/Users/Ozan/Desktop/newProduct.json')),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'User-Agent: dummy_dev',
    'Authorization: Basic MGM0N2Q4ODQtZmYyMi00NTFmLThlYjEtNDY3ZDMwMDk1NzgxOlRUcTdReU5oRUdhUw==',
    'Cookie: JSESSIONID=FB8184E3FE98EDB7C4BCAB0052E0291'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I just created a simple test.php file and put that code there and moddified a little.

```
<?php

echo "Curl Starts! ";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://mpop.hepsiburada.com/product/api/products/import",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
    'file'=> new CURLFILE('C:/Users/Ozan/Desktop/newProduct.json')
  ],
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "accept: application/json",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
    'User-Agent: dummy_dev',
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'dummyMerchantId' . ':' . 'dummySecretKeyPassword')
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

echo "Curl Ends! ";
?>
```

For some reason I get forbidden error as below:

```
Curl Starts! {"timestamp":"2024-03-29T12:45:45.064+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/api/products/import"}Curl Ends!
```

I checked and there is no IP whitelisting needed on the server.